# float object not callable error while calculating sum of list in Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

When i try to add up ***list*** elements it produces below error

```
print weights
print sum(weights)
```

I get the following error

```
[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
  TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-f2d5440b3427> in <module>()
      1 print weights
----> 2 print sum(weights)
      3 

 TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: Have you got a variable called "sum"? If you do it will be used ahead of the function.

Answer (score 5):

Somewhere in the unseen code above, you're assigning a value to `sum`.

Comment: Thanks (my bad) sum is a reserved word.Thanks a lot for your help